# thesis won't compile anymore!

Tags: errors, compiling

I opened up my thesis this morning to compile and nothing happens! It worked fine Saturday. LyX hangs and when I exported to .tex and tried to compile with TeX Shop it also hangs.
here is the console output:

```
`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./thesis_schneider_book-ucb.16.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
 icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
 lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spani
sh, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/Users/dschneid/Library/texmf/tex/latex/vnovathesis_hyperref.cls

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `vnovathesis_hyperref',
               but the document class provides `thesis'.

Document Class: thesis 2003/01/07

--------------------------------------------------------------
 +---+ Thesis Style (thesis.cls) version 1.10, January 2003
 +---+ for Villanova theses/dissertations.
 * Conforms to the Villanova Graduate
 * School "SPECIFICATIONS for Preparation of Master's Thesis
--------------------------------------------------------------
 based on URL: http://www.Colorado.EDU/ITS/docs/latex/ThesisClass


Class thesis Warning: Option 'letterpaper' superfluous. Ignored. on input line 
156.

(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/prettyref/prettyref.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rotfloat/rotfloat.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rotating/rotating.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/units.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hycolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/xcolor-patch.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/atveryend.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty)
No file thesis_schneider_book-ucb.16.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/lgrcmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ppl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/refcount.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))`
```

please help if you have any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: The same topic is discussed on [latex-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12890). @Dominik: I added code markup to the log file to make it more readble. This can be done by indenting lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: As it stands, I'd say this is much too open-ended to be suitable as a question here

Comment: Try to build a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of the problem.

Comment: I figured it out. I went to post a MWE and ran that just to check if it worked before I updated the preamble with that of my thesis. I checked the lines and realized I had inserted code to fix something and the compiler was hanging on that. All is well now.

Comment: that's fine. So I just close the question.